# Using BitBlt to mask background of bitmap C++

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, bitblt

I am making a small game with bitmaps representing objects and I am trying to mask the background using a bitmap mask. I looked it up on google and made two bitmaps. One of the ship and one as a mask. For the mask, I colored everything I wanted visible black and the background white. (If this should have been opposite, please let me know). I load the bitmaps as so:

```
HBITMAP bmpShip = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL,
                                     "C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Asteroids\\Starship.bmp",
                                     IMAGE_BITMAP,
                                     0,
                                     0,
                                     LR_LOADFROMFILE);

HBITMAP hShipMask = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL,
                                       "C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Asteroids\\StarshipMask.bmp",
                                       IMAGE_BITMAP,
                                       0,
                                       0,
                                       LR_LOADFROMFILE);
```

Now how can I use the BitBlt raster operations to display a bitmap without the background on the screen at a specific location. Without masking the background, this is what I have been doing:

```
Ship = CreateWindowEx(0,
                      "STATIC","",
                      SS_CENTERIMAGE | SS_REALSIZEIMAGE | SS_BITMAP | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                      10,
                      shipPos,
                      294,
                      86,
                      Background,
                      (HMENU)-1,
                      NULL, NULL);
SendMessage(Ship, STM_SETIMAGE,  (WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)bmpShip);
UpdateWindow(hWnd);

//And moving the window with MoveWindow()
```

Can anyone please tell me how I can mask the background and then move the window to a new location

Edit: By the way, Background is just another bitmap loaded in the same way as the others which the ship is displayed on top of.

Comment: You're loading the same file for the image and mask!

Comment: Sorry just a typo. I fixed it